# updateMfaAnswersForItem Flow

Tags: yodlee

Below is what I've received from Yodlee on how to remedy immediate 523 errors during a refresh:

1. First call getMfaQuestionsAndAnswersForItem API to get the Q&A for the account that are stored in Yodlee.
2. Then call updateMfaAnswersForItem API to update answers for the questions returned in getMfaQuestionsAndAnswersForItem API.

The above call will update the user's Q&A at Yodlee end. Once updated, Your technical team need to initiate the refresh the same way you are doing currently i.e. first call getMfaQuestionsAndAnswersForItem
API and then putMFARequest.

However after the first two steps it becomes a little unclear. After calling updateMfaAnswersForItem do we then perform a refresh (RefreshService.startRefresh5 call) and then jump into the MFA flow (getMfaQuestionsAndAnswersForItem then putMFARequest) or do we have to immediately jump into the  MFA flow of getMfaQuestionsAndAnswersForItem and then putMFARequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to handle 523 -

1. After the above mentioned 2 API calls. Trigger a refresh using startRefresh API and then go to MFA flow.

OR

2. Directly trigger a refresh using API and then go to MFA flow. This will provide you with the MFA questions , which answered correctly will result in a successful refresh.